# How to set locale in Nix shell on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, locale, nix

To demonstrate locale support in Ubuntu:

```bash
vagrant init ubuntu/jammy64
vagrant up
vagrant ssh
sudo apt-get -y install hello language-pack-nb
LC_MESSAGES=nb_NO.UTF-8 hello
```

This prints the expected, localised "Hei, verden!" message.

Let's try running the Nix package instead, following [the only locale hint I could find](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Locales):

```bash
sudo apt-get -y purge hello
yes | sh <(curl -L https://nixos.org/nix/install) --daemon
exit
vagrant ssh
nix-shell --packages hello
export LOCALE_ARCHIVE=/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
LC_MESSAGES=nb_NO.UTF-8 hello
```

This instead prints "Hello, world!". I also tried to `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` and set "nb_NO.UTF-8" as the default locale, but no go.

What do I need to do now to get the localised message inside the Nix shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I had to reconfigure locales in Ubuntu, adding the relevant locale to the configuration.

Second, even though the localisation of the package is in a directory called `share/locale/nb/LC_MESSAGES`, it was not enough to set `LC_MESSAGES=nb_NO.UTF-8`. I had to instead set `LANG=nb_NO.UTF-8`.

In other words, this seems to be the *minimum* steps:

```bash
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
nix-shell -p hello
export LOCALE_ARCHIVE=/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
LANG=nb_NO.UTF-8 hello
```